# Bootstrap pagination and using of <a> inside the <li> tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In accordance to Bootstrap docs the pagination syntax is the following:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I came to conclusion that it is necessary to embrace the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>` tag to make the pagination looks like Bootstrap design should look. But I'd like to use JS script as a click action instead of jumping to specified URL. If I'd use '#' sign as the href property this hashtag will appear in the web-browser address line which is not really "beautiful" and even can cause some bugs from my point of view.

So what should I do? Ignore? Strip hashtag and leave empty quotes? Dig into the CSS to make the pagination looks proper with no dependence of using `<a>` tag inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by simply adding a return false to your onclick-attribute. It would look something like this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="yourJsFunction(); return false;">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

This way the JS-Function will be called, but the browser will not redirect to the link's href.